# Need To Add Link to text of List Item without .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
console.log(data)
var link
$listSelector = $("#top5CompaniesList") //Your list element
$.each(data.result, function(i, obj) {
    $listSelector.append('<li>');
    link = $('<a href="dashboard.php#companyInfo?'+obj.symbol+'">'+obj.symbol+'</a>').click(function(){
        $('.nav-pills a[href=#companyInfo]').tab('show') ;
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        $('#companySearchInput').val(obj.symbol);
        $('#companySearchButton').click();
        return false;
    });
    $listSelector.append(link);
    $listSelector.append('<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata+'</li>');         
});
```

Using the code above I'm trying to add list items to a list that includes a link which I have custom behavior designed for. The behavior works, except that there's a line break on the page where each .append() call happens.I'd like the list item to appear as one unbroken line. I tried using both .wrap() and .wrapInner(), but those seem to replace the entire innerHTML of the list item. Honestly I know they're probably the solution but I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic. Any help or a push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue? My first guess would be use CSS to make the list inline or perhaps the `<br>` tag is causing your issue. But without seeing it its hard to say for sure.

Comment: `'<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata+'</li>'` isn't right: there's no matching opening tag for the `</li>`.

Comment: @Juhana Sorry about that. I edited the question to demonstrate where I'm putting the opening tag.

Comment: It's still wrong. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I figured it would be, but I wanted to show you my complete wrongness not just the partial wrongness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$listSelector.append('<li>');
// ...
$listSelector.append('<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata+'</li>');
```

First some theory. You can't add partial HTML to the document. The web page itself doesn't consist of HTML. It consists of elements, and HTML is only a markup language that represents those elements and tells the browser how to build them. Appending an open `<li>` element without closing it doesn't make sense in this perspective: you can't have half of an element in the DOM.

When you have `$listSelector.append('<li>')` you're appending an entire `<li>` element to the document. It's exactly equivalent to `$listSelector.append('<li></li>')`. When you later have `$listSelector.append('<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata+'</li>')` it's exactly equivalent to `$listSelector.append('<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata+'<li></li>')` – the browser doesn't "remember" that there was an open `<li>` tag earlier so it "fixes" the broken HTML.

The extra empty `<li>` elements are what cause the layout to look broken.

To fix it, first make the `<li>` element, then add its contents to it, and then append it to the parent:

```
link = $('<a href="dashboard.php#companyInfo?'+obj.symbol+'">'+obj.symbol+'</a>').click(function(){
    $('.nav-pills a[href=#companyInfo]').tab('show') ;
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    $('#companySearchInput').val(obj.symbol);
    $('#companySearchButton').click();
    return false;
});

$('<li>')
    .append(link)
    .append('<br> Otherdata: '+obj.otherdata)
    .appendTo($listSelector);
```